# Determine if a method call is from an IBAction button or a self call

Tags: objective-c

I have a method `-(IBAction)slotSpin:(id)sender {do stuff }`. It is executed from a button press and also from within the `ViewController` using a self call. How can I from within this method tell how it was called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass `nil` as `sender` when calling it from the view controller:

```
[self slotSpin:nil];
```

then test with:

```
-(IBAction)slotSpin:(id)sender {
    if (sender) {
        // called from button action (sender = UIButton *)
    } else {
        // called from view controller
    }
}
```